# How could be diff(X) converted to OpenCV or Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv

How could be differentiation implemented within XCode Objective C or OpenCV ? (diff(BWImage) in matlab that is http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement it, it is already done, that's what `cv::Sobel` does. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_image_filtering.html#cv-sobel